# Pipe for loop with awk and if

Tags: linux, bash, awk, cron, for

I'm trying to create a cron job that checks the status of certain worker machines and triggers a webhook:

It works, but I'm not sure that this is the best approach:

```bsh
for i in $(oc get nodes | awk 'FNR>1 {print $2}');do if [[ $i != 'Ready' ]];then <TRIGGER_WEBHOOK>;fi;done
```

Output of `oc get nodes`

```bsh
# oc get nodes
NAME                         STATUS   ROLES    AGE    VERSION
master1                      Ready    master   27h    v1.20.0+bafe72f-1054
....
worker4                      Ready    worker   10h    v1.20.0+bafe72f-1054
```

Any advice to improve it. Thx

Comment: What is the output of `oc get nodes`?

Comment: My bad I've added

Comment: Is the string `# oc get nodes` **really** the first line of the output of `oc get nodes`? If not then please [edit] your question to remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one thing I can see that I might change is removing the `if`:

```
for i in $(oc get nodes | awk 'FNR > 1 && $2 != "Ready" { print $2 }'); do
    <TRIGGER API>
done
```

Comment: Elegant stuff there, thx a lot. so basically if I understand correctly you've put the IF in awk syntax ?

Comment: precisely: it only outputs the second field if it's not 'Ready'.

Comment: @dejdej You don't need the first field or anything else that identifies what's "not ready"?

Comment: +1, but won't this just output the status column?   It's what the OP's code had, but they probably should have been printing $1 to get the node name.   `awk '$2 == "Ready" {print $1}'` - that can be used that with a for loop or pipe into `xargs -r -n 1 trigger-api-command`.    Or maybe just exit with 0 if all status columns after FNR=1 are "Ready" and 1 otherwise: `if oc get nodes | awk 'NR >1 && $2 != "Ready" { exit 1}'; then trigger-api-command; fi`

Comment: which variant to use depends on whether each node needs to be "triggered" individually if it's not Ready, or if just one trigger needs to be run if any of them aren't Ready.

Comment: on second thoughts, `awk '$2 == "Ready" {print $1}'` in my first comment is just wrong.  it should be your test `FNR > 1 && $2 != "Ready"` but print $1 instead of $2 to get a list of nodes that aren't ready.

Comment: That is what I thought too but I did not want to alter the _behavior of the stated code in the OP_; the request was for a refactor and not a debug.  It's possible in this use-case the unshown API call is a one-shot to reset all nodes or somesuch (in which case doing it once per un-`Ready` node is still probably suboptimal) but again, that was beyond the scope of the question.